# Is it possible to access Sabre programatically without using their Web services?

Tags: web-services, api, networking, sabre

I'm looking into developing a reservations systems using the GDS Sabre. I will have access to their normal system via a terminal, however their Web Services are too expensive and I'm looking for a workaround.

Anyone with experience using this system know if it's possible to access their terminal programatically? I'm thinking about doing a simple program that can search information in Sabre using terminal commands but I have no clue on how the connection to Sabre's server works. (A simple TCP connection would be ideal)

Comment: You could probably screen scrape their terminal (that what the original way you accessed Sabre, back before they implemented their CORBA backbone). But yea, thats leaping 15 years into the past - its hard to implement, hard to maintain, hard to scale, all around unpleasant to deal with.

Comment: Why screen scraping? Is the terminal usually accessed via a website?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to what you want and we can help you. You will need the MySabre API or Emulator API license from Sabre.